# sum(ofProperty: "amount") giving error in swift 5

Tags: realm

I am using swift5 and I am trying to sum by property like this:

```
let total = realm.objects(Purchase.self).sum(ofProperty: "amount")
```

but i get this error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easist solution is to let the compiler know what kind of result the sum will be.

Like this

```
let total: Double = realm.objects(Purchase.self).sum(ofProperty: "orderProperty")
print(total)
```

This tells the compiler than total will always be a Double

As a side note, Double's are (generally) not a good type to work with for financial situations. Look into Decimal (akin to NSDecimal and Decimal128)

```
@Persisted var decimal: Decimal128
```

in newer versions